# Add Email Field in gift-message Magento 2

Tags: magento2, giftmessage

I want to add new field emai in gift-message?
[image]

Comment: Please add more details what have you tried so far and with email you want to add this gift message

Comment: By default there are 3 fields to, from and message. I want to extend the functionality and add new field email to save in database. But after adding new field I'm getting 500 error that this field is not defined in the gift model class. I tried to extend the class using di.xml but was unable to do so. And I'm unable to find the save method of this action as this is rest api. Could you please help me to override and save this extra field.

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar